# Getting an error while starting rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I just installed the rabbitmq and getting an error while starting it. Not sure why is this error coming up.

```
[root@astroHeka run]# /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server start
Starting rabbitmq-server: rmdir: failed to remove `/var/run/rabbitmq':     Directory not empty
FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
rabbitmq-server.
```

I manually removed the folder and tried restarting but still the same issue.

Comment: Please post the message in: `check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}`

Comment: This is in error: /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server: line 50: erl: command not found      This is in log: ^[[60G[^[[0;31mFAILED^[[0;39m]^M

Comment: Did you install erlang?

Comment: I installed erlang but seems to be some problem there. How can i verify that?